# Javascript: Why is the "texture" parameter undefined?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm new to Javascript and I'm playing around with WebGL and getting the error, `"texture.image is undefined"` in the code below.  When I debug it using Firebug, the `this.starshipTexture.image` is being initialized and loaded with the image file just fine, but when `handleLoadedTexture(texture)` is called, the `texture` parameter shows up as undefined.

```
    starship.prototype.initTexture = function () {
        var starshipImage = new Image();
        this.starshipTexture = gl.createTexture();
        this.starshipTexture.image = starshipImage;

        starshipImage.onload = function () {
            handleLoadedTexture(this.starshipTexture)
        }
        starshipImage.src = "starship.gif";
    }

    function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        //CRASHES ON THIS NEXT LINE
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    }
```

Thanks for your wisdom!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `this`, inside that "load" handler, won't be what you need it to be.

Instead, stuff it in a temporary variable before setting up the handler:

```
var theStarship = this;
starshipImage.onload = function () {
        handleLoadedTexture(theStarship.starshipTexture)
};
```

Comment: Or you can use `Function.bind` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind  `starshipImage.onload = handleLoadedTexture.bind(window, this.starshipTexture)`

Answer (score 0):

To add to Pointy's answer, you could do this (which takes advantage of the marvelous javascript duck typing):

```
starshipImage.targetObject = this;
starshipImage.onload = function () {
    handleLoadedTexture(this.targetObject.starshipTexture)
};
```

Comment: Attaching an extra property just for this purpose is a waste of resources and hackish. A local variable makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to Pointy's answer is using [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which I find more elegant, but does the same thing and is usually a matter of choice.

```
starshipImage.onload = handleLoadedTexture.bind(window,  this.starshipTexture);
```

That creates a "bound" function, that is, a function where the context (`this`, which is not needed in this case) and the arguments to the function are set before the function is called.